# Firebase Unity - Missing or insufficient permissions

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, google-cloud-firestore

I've been using Firebase (Authentication, Cloud Storage, ...) for almost two years with Unity without an issue.
For a few weeks now, when I press play in Unity, I got an error `Missing or insufficient permissions`. After debugging, I found out that when I call :

```
FirebaseFirestore.DefaultInstance.Collection("users").Document("userID")
   .GetSnapshotAsync().ContinueWithOnMainThread(task => { ... });
```

the `task.IsFaulted` returns `true` and the exception message is `Missing or insufficient permissions`.

It's worth noting, that before getting a snapshot of the document, the sign in process has been done correctly (Firebase Authentication automatically sign in the user).

What I did is add `FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance.SignOut()` when the `task.IsFaulted` and tried to sign in again, and I have the same error.

BUT, if I wait a few minutes while in Play mode, and then try to sign in again, there is no errors, and the sign in is successful. Therefore I don't think it's a problem regarding the Firebase rules, especially since I didn't change anything recently.

I can continue working, but it's quite troublesome to have to wait a few minutes every time that I press Play to try a new feature.

Do you have any ideas of what I can do?

I'm using Unity LTS 2019.4.22 and Firebase 7.2.0

EDIT:

When I try on a iPhone or Android, instead of directly in the Editor, the problem doesn't occur. When I launch the app, I'm automatically signed in, and the userData in the database is fetched correctly.
Instead in the Editor, I'm automatically signed in, but then, when trying to fetch the user, I'm getting the `Missing or insufficient permissions`.

I've Debug.Log to be sure that the user is correctly signed in before trying to fetch the database,[image: as shown here]

EDIT2:

Here is the code that create those logs.

1 - I initialise Firebase and listen to the `StateChanged` event

2 - When the event is triggered, I log the first message, then I check if the user is signed in, and then I log the second message with his id (I use the code provided in the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/unity/start#set_an_authentication_state_change_event_handler_and_get_user_data))

3 - I then try to fetch the user document, and if the `task.IsFaulted`, I sign out and then I log the error message

[image: code]

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to access data before the user is signed in. It's hard to see why that is though, without an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I will try to create an MCVE, but I'm sure that the user is signed in. I'm using the authentication state change event handler as in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/unity/start#set_an_authentication_state_change_event_handler_and_get_user_data). When pressing Play, I first receive the `Debug.Log` saying that the user is signed in and I print his ID. THEN, I receive the error `Missing or insufficient permissions`

Comment: Editing your question to show the code that logs the UID and its output sounds like good steps toward and MCVE.

Comment: I will do that. And I will also add the fact that this problem only occur in the Editor. If I build and try on my iPhone, I can sign in directly, without waiting.

Comment: Could you share the code that triggers the creation of these logs?

Comment: Of course, I just edited the post

Comment: This is an odd one, I could not replicate it on my end and everything looks correct, and the fact that it does not occur in your devices makes it more strange, have you tried with different versions of Firebase?

Comment: What's even more strange is that I have the same project on both my mac and my windows and on my mac the problem always occur, on my windows without debugging the problem never occurs and on my windows while debugging (debugging on Visual Studio with or without breaking points, then playing on Unity), the problem always occurs

Comment: hmmm, I think it might be a good idea for you to reach out to [Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support) or open a Bug in [Google's issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=530136&template=0) as this might be a bug specific to windows environments.

Comment: Okay thank you, I will contact them and then update this post when I have news